# How to pass component in React mui menuItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, menuitem

I imported Report.js component and want to use it in "menuitem", I tried this in button and its working perfectly

```
 import Reports from 'new-components/Reports/Reports'   //ontop

 <Button> 
    <Reports pid={pid} />          //working
 </Button>
```

but when i tried this same in "menuitem" than its not working

```
<MenuItem >
  <Reports pid={pid} />            //not working
</MenuItem>
```

i also tried with passing component in onClick function, i know we can only pass function in onClick, but this gives desired result with error

```
<MenuItem onClick={<Reports pid={name}/>}> 
     <Reports pid={name}/>
</MenuItem>
```

It throws a error " *Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.*"

Reports.js

```js
  return (
     <CSVLink {...csvReport}>Export CSV</CSVLink>
     )
```

Comment: onClick Expected as function not a component. Pass only in child of menuItem instead of onClick `<MenuItem><Reports pid={pid} /></MenuItem>` [ref](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu-item)

Comment: yes that was the first thing i did, but thats not working

Comment: If it is working for you in `<Buttons>` then it should also work for `MenuItem` as well. Bcs there nothing difference in both code

Comment: its only working when i also put it in onClick={<Reports/>}, but offcourse that will throw error as it will not return function.

Comment: if i put component as a child, it shows the download link but didnt download the CSV as it is being return from Report.js

Comment: what is in `CSVLink` ? is it working when you are using inside of `Buttons` ?

Comment: Yes thats properly working in button. I think there is some issues with menuItem.

Comment: I would avoid naming two components the same way. It's hard to tell what actually gets executed if you don't know what you've imported exactly. It could just be a misimport.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass your `Reports` element via the `component` prop of `MenuItem`:

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
  return <MenuItem component={<Reports pid={pid} />} />;
}
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu-item/#props

Comment: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.